# Apache Velocity to replace backslash with two backslashes

Tags: phpstorm, velocity

I want to replace a single backslash with two backslashes within an Apache Velocity template in PhpStorm. Sadly, nothing seems to work. Here are a few attempts of mine, none of which worked.

```
${VAR.replace("\\", "\\\\")}
${VAR.replace("\\", "\\\\\\")}
${VAR.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\")}
${VAR.replace("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")}
```

I tried various other combinations, including `${esc.b}` and `${esc.backslash}` which are provided by Velocity. Absolutely nothing works.

I want to transform the namespace into a quoted string within a PHP file, that is why I need two backslashes in the output instead of one.

*Any ideas?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `replaceAll` as `replace` works with *single characters only*.
2. Do it using `#set` instruction

Example:

```
#set($newVar = $namespace.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\"))
$newVar
```

Example input data for `namespace` variable: `qwe\asd\asd`

Result:

```
qwe\\asd\\asd
```

Comment: Gosh, my Java days are too long gone, could found that myself in the appropriate documentation. But I just did not think that `replace()` works like `strtr()` in PHP. The `#set()` is not necessary, it is a call, print, and forget invocation.